# Backbone collection from nested array

Tags: javascript, arrays, backbone.js

How Can I make collection from nested array? This is how array looks like before:

[image]

```
var OrdersCollection =  Backbone.Collection.extend({
      model: OrderModel,
      url : '/api/orders',
});

var OrderModel = Backbone.Model.extend({});


var orders = this.model;
this.collection = new OrdersCollection(orders);
```

Now I have array like:

[image]

So I have to make collection from array inside rows... Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [.parse](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-parse)

```
var OrdersCollection =  Backbone.Collection.extend({
      model: OrderModel,
      url : '/api/orders',
      parse: function(response) {
        return response.rows;
      }
});
```